# How can I get info from database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a database `CarsDB` with a table `Car` with some columns (like mileage or model)

And I want to get info from that table in a controller I write:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.CarsDB.ToList()):
}
```

But I'm getting an error (something like *method CarsDB not found*). The error is long and I don't know hot to translate it to English :( Also, when I write db, the only suggetions I'm getting are "Equals", "GetHashCode" and some others, not with `CarsDB`

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? Are you using LINQ-to-SQL, or something else?

Comment: What is `db`?  Where/how is it initialized?  Does it have a property on it called `CarsDB`?  Should it?  What is the actual error?  You may not understand the error, but we can help with that if you include it in your question instead of just a vague description of what you think you remember it saying.

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`db.Cars.ToList()`

You need to query the table (cars) - right now you're saying "select everything from the CarsDB database", rather than "select everything from the Cars table in the CarsDB database".

To clarify - your `db` variable should be an instance of a data context or entities.

Full code should look something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    CarsDB db = new CarsDB();
    return View(db.Cars.ToList()):
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework you could do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (CarsDB dataContext = new CarsDB())
    {
        return View(dataContext.Cars.ToList()):
    }
}
```

This will also assure automatic disposal of your data context.